# Matrix Which Is Half Read-Only: Implementing the Iterator derefrence

Tags: c++, iterator, constants

I have this vector class (using std::vector), in which I define a range of accessible elements between min and max

```
template <typename T>
class MyVec {
    vector<T> vec;
    int rangemin;
    int rangemax; 
    //All kinds of methods

    const T& operator[](int i) const {
        //Conditions on i, ~NOT TAKING INTO CONSIDERATION RANGE~ and throwing exception
        return static_cast<const T&>(vec[i]);
    }

    T& operator[](int i) {
        //Conditions on i, ~TAKING INTO CONSIDERATION RANGE~ and throwing exception
        return vec[i];
    }
};
```

And then I use this class to define a class of matrices which some elements are only read only (By setting the range on each row)

```
template <typename T>
class MyMatrix {
    vector<MyVec<T>> arr;
    size_t rows, columns;
    bool isUpper;
    //All kinds of methods

    MyVec<T>& operator[](int row) {
        //Checking conditions on row and throwing exception
        return arr[row];
    }

    MyVec<T> const& operator[](int row) const {
        //Checking conditions on row and throwing exception
        return arr[row];
    }

    class iterator;
}
```

Now this mechanism does infact work when I try to write to an illegal element by `m[i][j] = val`
but when I implement the following iterator

```
class MtmMat<T>::iterator {
    const MyMat<T>* mat;
    int row, column;

    friend class MyMat<T>;
    //Some methods

public:
    T& operator*() {
        return const_cast<T&>((*matrix)[row][column]);
    }
    T const& operator*() const {
        return (*matrix)[row][column];
    }
};
```

When I have an iterator which points to an element which should be read only, It is possible to write into! For some reason, it goes the method in `MyVec` which doesn't take range into consideration. How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `const_cast<T&>((*matrix)[row][column])` oof...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm trying to implement for example an upper triangular matrix, in which case I don't want the elements below the diagonal to be written into

Comment: Then don't write into them. What is the purpose of all this machinery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you meant:

```
 return const_cast<MyMat<T>&>(*matrix)[row][column];
```

That is, your `()` are in the wrong place and you cast too late.

However this design looks exceedingly fragile and potentially dangerous. I strongly recommend reconsidering your goal.